# Java 'final' instance variable - visibility and propagation of variable's internal state

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, final

While reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) related to Threads and Locks, a sentence describing `final` keyword attracted me:

> Correspondingly, compilers are allowed to keep the value of a final field cached in a register and not reload it from memory in situations where a non-final field would have to be reloaded.

Does it mean, that if I declare a `final Object object = ...` as an instance variable and then access it (modify its inner state - `object.state`) from anonymous inner classes (multiple instances of `Runnable`), then the value of `object.state` could actually be read/written from/into CPU cache and it (value of `object.state`) could be out of sync across those `Runnable` instances?

So if I want to be sure, that the value of `object.state` is properly propagated across all the threads I have to declare the `object` as `volatile Object object` instead?

Thank you.

---

Edit: I have edited my original question. And now I know I misunderstood the documentation so the answer to my last question is **NO** - `volatile/final Object object` has no effect on `object.state` - it depends how the `object.state` is declared, initialized and/or accessed.

Thanks to the @Burak Serdar for the answer!

Comment: What you are reading says that the final field can remain in one of the registers because there is no real need to reach memory for something that can’t change

Comment: What different values? A `final` variwble can ony have one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a `final Object object=...`, the final value is the reference to the object, not the internal state of the object. It means than nothing can modify `object`, it does not say that nothing can modify, say, `object.value`. So the variable `object` can be cached, which does not mean the internal state of `object` can be cached.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. It have just kicked my butt :)

Answer (score -1):

Final will not help you with threading issues the way you hope, sorry.
Volatile may help in some situations, but you may need a lock.

From the Oracle tutorials:

-Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).
-Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile (including long and double variables).

That means your object will not be immediately updated between reads and writes, but it will be consistent within one read/write.

Comment: Volatile read/writes are memory read/writes with a memory barrier. Nonvolatile read/writes don't have memory barriers, meaning a write may not be immediately visible to other threads.

Comment: I would delete the answer. It is a can of worms if it were code. But do as you please

Comment: And it does not really answer the question

Comment: @efekctive - I'm sorry, can you explain? The question is about the use of final, which I gave an answer to in the first line. Then, it was asked about volatile, which I tried to shed some light on by referring to Oracle's tutorial. What is so wrong with this answer?

Comment: The question is basically bad. Locks, threads, final bars, registers then it asks if the solution is volatiles. The solution to what?